# Pass parameters to SOAP method

Tags: java, android

I've got an app that connects to our .NET web service and I'm finding that we are creating the same method for each web service method but the only difference is the parameters and the web service method.  I'm looking for a way to have the following method accept parameters and then it could be more useful to manage 1 vs. several.

**Current Method**  *NameSpace, URL, argName, argValue are all defined at the top of the class.

```
public static Document GetTickets() {
    try { 
        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NameSpace, "GetTickets");         
        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.dotNet = true;
        request.addProperty(argName, argValue);

        request.addProperty("Customer", "ABC");
        request.addProperty("Local", "USA");

        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        androidHttpTransport.call("RemoteWebService/GetTickets", envelope); 

        SoapPrimitive responseData = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();
        if (responseData != null)
        {
            //get the factory
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            //Using factory get an instance of document builder
            DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
            //parse using builder to get DOM representation of the XML file
            InputSource is = new InputSource(new StringReader(responseData.toString()));
            return db.parse(is);
        }
        else
            return null;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Errors.LogError(e);
        return null;
    }
}
```

I'd like it to be something along these lines:

```
public static Document GetTickets(String WebServiceMethod, ArrayList Params) {
    try { 
        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NameSpace, WebServiceMethod);         
        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.dotNet = true;

        //Syntax is wrong, I know, but just want to show what I'm looking to do:
        foreach(Parameter p in Params)
            request.addProperty(p[0].value, p[1].value);

        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        androidHttpTransport.call("RemoteWebService/" + WebServiceMethod, envelope); 

        SoapPrimitive responseData = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();
        if (responseData != null)
        {
            //get the factory
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            //Using factory get an instance of document builder
            DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
            //parse using builder to get DOM representation of the XML file
            InputSource is = new InputSource(new StringReader(responseData.toString()));
            return db.parse(is);
        }
        else
            return null;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Errors.LogError(e);
        return null;
    }
}
```

I've tried a couple of different attempts at this but getting lots of errors.  I know it's rather simple but can't seem to figure it out atm.

Comment: Well, as I said, I tried this with an array, a multi-dimension array, and a few others but kept getting an index out of range error, which I know means that the index of the element that's being accessed is outside the bounds of the array, but I've been so frustrated with this that I deleted everything and started from scratch again.  So sorry, I don't have the error handy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I seem to have figured out a nice approach but welcome any feedback as to if this is ok or not:

Created a class called Parameter:

```
public class Parameter {

    private String mParameterName;
    private String mParameterValue;

    // [[ ParameterName

    public void setParameterName(String ParameterName){
        mParameterName = ParameterName;
    }

    public String getParameterName(){
        return mParameterName;
    }

    // ]]

    // [[ ParameterValue

    public void setParameterValue(String ParameterValue){
        mParameterValue = ParameterValue;
    }

    public String getParameterValue(){
        return mParameterValue;
    }

    // ]]
}
```

And then modified my method to accept a List of this type:

```
public static Document GetWebServiceData(String WebServiceMethod, List<Parameter> Params) {
    try { 
        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NameSpace, WebServiceMethod);         
        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.dotNet = true;

        for(Parameter param : Params)
            request.addProperty(param.getParameterName(), param.getParameterValue());

        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        androidHttpTransport.call(NameSpace + "/" + WebServiceMethod, envelope); 

        SoapPrimitive responseData = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();
        if (responseData != null)
        {
            //get the factory
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();

            //Using factory get an instance of document builder
            DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

            //parse using builder to get DOM representation of the XML file
            InputSource is = new InputSource(new StringReader(responseData.toString()));
            return db.parse(is);
        }
        else
            return null;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Errors.LogError(e);
        return null;
    }
}
```

And then it simply gets accessed like so:

```
    List<Parameter> Params = new ArrayList<Parameter>();

    Parameter Param = new Parameter();
    Param.setParameterName("Customer");
    Param.setParameterValue("ABC");
    Params.add(Param);

    Param = new Parameter();
    Param.setParameterName("Local");
    Param.setParameterValue("USA");
    Params.add(Param);

    Document doc = GetWebServiceData("GetTickets", Params);
```

Works like a charm!  Hope this helps someone else out...